# What happens to "Open with Explorer" after Internet Explorer is discontinued?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer, edge

Anyone know if the "Open with Explorer" feature will be available on the new Edge browser once Internet Explorer is discontinued?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it will not work.
Best way forward is to start using OneDrive for Business, use browser Apps that mimic File Explorer in a browser, use apps that need to be installed on clients or only use the browser.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

That command is not available in Edge. From [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/troubleshoot-issues-using-open-with-explorer):

> The Open with Explorer command doesn't work in the Microsoft Edge browser.

Microsoft suggests two alternatives that don't require Internet Explorer:

- [Move or copy files in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-or-copy-files-in-sharepoint-00e2f483-4df3-46be-a861-1f5f0c1a87bc)
- [Sync SharePoint files with the OneDrive sync app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-and-teams-files-with-the-onedrive-sync-app-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88)